Angular material mat-list-item
How to vertically align content in mat-list-item?
In my case it contains:
 `
   <mat-list-item>
      <a>.....</a>
   </mat-list-item>`
  

I tried this in css
  mat-list-item {
   display: inline-block;
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
   vertical-align: center;
  }
 
  
   a{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
   }
  

but it didn't work.

Have you tried margin : auto 0 ?

mat-list-items are vertically aligned by default, the code you provided doesn't show the real problem here. If you share more we might be able to see why it isn't vertically aligned in this case.

We can use the below CSS, I use width:100% to make full width and text-align: center to align the text. The parent span I convert to flex, instead of the list item
CSS:
.center-align-list {
  mat-list-item .mdc-list-item__content > span {
    display: flex;
    .center-align {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}

HTML:
<mat-list role="list" class="center-align-list">
  <mat-list-item role="listitem"
    ><a class="center-align" href="#">Item 1</a></mat-list-item
  >
  <mat-list-item role="listitem"
    ><a class="center-align" href="#">Item 2</a></mat-list-item
  >
  <mat-list-item role="listitem"
    ><a class="center-align" href="#">Item 3</a></mat-list-item
  >
</mat-list>

Stackblitz Demo

text-align: center; did the job
